# Answered question poke queue

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

As a relatively new user here, there are about 8000+ questions that precede my arrival here.  Sometimes I see questions that pique my interests in the related question sidebar, and sometimes I sift through a tag.  But I like seeing the random questions that get "poked" to the top of the list.

However, those questions are limited to no accepted answer questions, with the presumed goal of bringing them to the attention of someone who might answer.  Sometimes, I find questions with accepted answers that I feel I have something to add to, or am just interested in looking into now that I see it.

Is it possible to make a queue of randomly poked accepted answer questions?  Maybe it could go into its own queue, as an option on the top bar next to featured and active etc., so that new users can get some random exposure to older questions without systematically sorting through the entire volume of asked questions.

Comment: I don't know about new queues, but have you explored the advanced search options?  You can search for questions in particular tags (or with particular text) that have N answers, have accepted answers, and maybe even have scores in certain ranges (not sure about that last).  (For heavier-duty searching there's the Data Explorer, if you're comfortable writing SQL queries.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio re the Data Explorer see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19412

Answer (score 4):

Interesting idea. A queue would indeed be best AFAICT for the purpose you mention. However, in case that purpose is adjudged not important enough to warrant a queue, perhaps Stack Exchange could add instead a "go to a random question" link (like [Wikipedia has](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aRandom_page)).

(Personally, I'm not sure either one is necessary. I'm just putting forth the alternative proposal.)

Comment: Yeah, I never claimed necessity.  But there are a lot of not strictly "necessary" features to make this site more accessible. It would just be a nice addition, for newer users.