# Random Questions

Tags: feature-request

I don't know if this is possible, but would there be any way to add a "random question" button to MY, for people who are just looking to gain knowledge, but have nothing particular in mind that they are looking for?  I was thinking something like what Wikipedia has:

[image: a "Random article" link, with a "Load a random article [alt-shift-x]" tooltip, below the Wikipedia site logo]

Comment: See https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2049/13438

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following through a link from the [Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5551) msh210 pointed to, you can get a random list of positive-score MY questions by clicking here:

[image: RANDOM button]